# User Input for Day in Month

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the user to input the correct day for the month in question, e.g. no good entering 30 for February, or 31 for June. This is my code, but I keep getting a syntax error for the `elif` statement. Why is that?

```
if month == ('February') and (LeapYear == False):
        maxday == 28
if month == ('February') and (LeapYear == True):
        maxday == 29
if month == ('April') or ('June') or ('September') or ('November'):
        maxday == 30
else:
        maxday == 31 
while True:
        which_day = int(input("Enter a positive number, 1 to 31 or to quit: "))
        if which_day < 0 or which_day > maxday:
                print("day for month incorrect - try again..please!")
                continue
elif which_day <= maxday:
        print("OK, we can go from here...!")
        print (maxday , which_day)
        break
print("All done!")
```

Comment: Look at the indentation - your `elif` appears to be matched to a `while`, which doesn't make much sense!

Comment: ..I just didn't spot that - I was looking for all sorts of problems that patently didn't exist! Thanks for pointing it out.